# How to prevent Foundation.framework from being linked

Tags: xcode, linker, clang, llvm-clang

I have a dynamic library project that uses Objective-C but does not use Foundation.

It works, but Foundation is being implicitly linked.

How do I prevent that in Xcode?

I thought there was a build setting for this, but I'm not seeing it now.

Answer (score 1):

Of course as soon as I ask the question I find the answer.

It's "LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES" ("Link With Standard Libraries")